# the server responded with a status of 431 (Request Header Fields Too Large) chrome Angular

Tags: angular, httprequest

I'am working in a project in angular 7. When a try to do a request to the server with a long list of ids in argument. I get an error 431  (Request Header Fields Too Large).
This error appends only in chrome browser. In safari, edge and firefox, all works fine.

Is there any solution to remedy this problem on chrome ?

Thanks,

Comment: please add your code and error. That will make it easy to understand.

Comment: Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 431 (Request Header Fields Too Large)
That's the only error chrome gave me

I don't have any error in server side. The request seems to be stop before.

Comment: @Matthieu How did you resolve this? I'm experiencing the same issue on Chrome whereas works for IE

Comment: Seems to be issue with specific node version 12.x

Answer (score 4):

This error can happen if your server sends too big headers, **including cookies**. Try to `clean browser cookies` for this site

Comment: I cannot clean the cookie, we save differents informations in it. The request works in production but not in localhost. Why the comportement between prod and localhost should be different about the cookies ?

Comment: Try to clean the cache for this site without the cookies and see if that works